# Can an activex control be launched from a local html file?

Tags: webserver, activex

Is a web server required for executing an activeX control?
Could the html calling the .dll files be off server?
Could you distribute the cab file and the html file and simply ask another user to run the cab and then launch the html file in a browser?

Comment: By default, it cannot: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/23/understanding-local-machine-zone-lockdown-restricted-this-webpage-from-running-scripts-or-activex-controls.aspx

Comment: Thanks Noseratio "Mark of the web" is what I was missing.